# KeyHolder.getKey() pode retornar null - Spring Boot JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

É o seguinte, sou iniciante em Spring e estou fazendo um método que vai inserir uma nova linha em uma tabela do Banco de Dados e esse metodo vai retornar o `Id` novo que foi gerado pelo Banco, estou fazendo desta forma:

```
public Profissional insert(Profissional profissional) {

    PreparedStatementCreator psc = connection -> {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into profissional(texto) values(?)",
                new String[] { "id" });

        ps.setString(1, profissional.getDsNomeProfissional());

        return ps;
    };

    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    this.jdbc.update(psc, keyHolder);

    profissional.setIdProfissional(keyHolder.getKey().longValue());

    return profissional;
}
```

e está funcionando e retornando o `id` gerado pelo banco, porem nesta linha `profissional.setIdProfissional(keyHolder.getKey().longValue());` a `IDE` esta me avisando que `keyHolder.getKey().longValue()` pode retornar nulo, e estou preucupado com isso mas também com duvida pq no [Docs do Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) esta dizendo que este é o jeit certo, isso é possivel de aconteçer mesmo? Se sim, alguém pode me explicar se tem algum outro jeito de fazer este código sem perigo de retornar um `Id` nulo?

(Obs: essa é uma pergunta mais informativa para caso alguma outra pessoa tenha esta mesma duvida que eu.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta é antiga, mas como passei por esse problema recentemente, ai vai:

O que acontece é que uma variável Number (ou qualquer outro wrapper Integer, Long, Double, etc...), pode receber um valor nulo, por isso, em um caso hipotético onde o KeyHolder tenha um valor null, a conversão irá estourar um NPe, por isso, nosso amigo compilador exibe essa advertência.

Para resolver este caso, em especifico, basta:

```
if (keyHolder.getKey() != null) {
    profissional.setIdProfissional(keyHolder.getKey().longValue());
}
```

Esse código pode gerar outros problemas, ex: não deveria ser inserido um valor com idProfissional = null... Mas ai é outro caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado.